# How to force the reading of Console.In?

Tags: f#

I have a very simple code

```
let R= [for i in (Console.In.ReadLine()).Split[|' '|]-> int i]

printfn "%A" R
printfn "%A" R
```

I would like that every time I call R, the function reads the console, but it does not. How can I manage it ?

Comment: `R` isn't a function; it's a value.

Comment: I understand now the difference, For me a function without arguments could be written without parenthesis, it is the first time I hava a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it a function:

```
let R() = [for i in (Console.In.ReadLine()).Split[|' '|]-> int i]

printfn "%A" (R())
printfn "%A" (R())
```